# How to open a new tab upon clicking a button inside frame in playwright?

Tags: iframe, playwright, playwright-test

Below is the method that i have tried but it is not working

```
 await page.keyboard.down('Control'),
 await page.frameLocator('iframe[name="entity_browser_iframe_eb_banner_slides"]').locator('#edit').click(), // in popup
  await page.keyboard.up('Control'),
```

Above lines of code is not opening the new tab

My Outcome should be
1)Click a button inside frame and open the link in new tab
I have also tried picking up getAttribute for href

But href look like this in DOM

<a href="#" class=""> </a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the click methods 'modifiers' to emulate a control click in a browser which will open a new tab:

From version 1.27, you can use getByRole

```
await page
      .frameLocator('iframe[name="foo"]')
      .getByRole('link', { name: 'bar baz' })
      .click({ modifiers: ['Control'] })
```

Instead of getByRole, you can just use normal locators if you wish:

```
await page
      .frameLocator('iframe[name="foo"]')
      .locators(`text='bar baz'`)
      .click({ modifiers: ['Control'] }),
```

That will definitely work in Chrome but have not tested in other browsers.

If you need to actually do something with the new tab, you could hook the context.waitForEvent('page') inside a Promise.all followed by the click and return the new page to interact with.

Comment: This is the error i am getting "page.frameLocator(...).getByRole is not a function" ..i couldn't find "getbyrole" method

Comment: Ah. What version of Playwright are you running with? .getByRole(...) was added in v1.27 but you don't need to use that if you don't want.  You can still just use normal locators.  Will update my reply above with other way etc.